# Orthogonally aligning an object by making the normal of one of it's faces perpendicular to the normal of the face it should be aligned to

Tags: modeling, normals

The question sounds a bit loaded but the essence of the problem is quite simpel.
Consider the following situation:

I have a plane `p`, angled at arbitrary angles and an object made up of multiple faces, one of which, `o`, I want to use to align the object perpendicular to `p`.
[image: current situation]

The desired result would be:
[image: (faked) final result]

I would need some way to align the normal vector of my reference face `o` to the normal vector of `p` **and** transform the rest of the object along with it.

[Here is a file with a demo of the problem](https://blend-exchange.com/b/n0debE7g)